Pagination in Power Query using SearchAfter
I'm currently working in power query to do some api calls from SailPoint and need to paginate through thousands of data points. The api requires you to use the searchafter parameter in the query body, but I'm having trouble getting this to work dynamically. This is my current code, using the pagenumber to determine whether or not the searchafter parameter should be used. If I set searchafter to a static id value, the query works fine, but once I try to use the "if" statement to fill in the space, I get errors.
let
    access_token = #"token from previous step",

    fetchPage = (nextID as nullable text, limit as number, pagenum as number) =>
    let 
        api_url = "some_url",
        searchAfterPart = if pagenum >1 then Text.Format(", ""searchAfter"": [""{0}""]", {nextID}) else "", // adding this to the body is when it stops working
        headers = [
            #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & access_token,
            #"Content-Type" = "application/json"
        ],
        body = Text.ToBinary(
            "{
                ""indices"": [""identities""],
                ""query"": {
                    ""query"": ""*"" 
                },
                ""sort"": [""id""] " & searchAfterPart & "
            }"
        ),
        response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_url, [Headers=headers, Content=body])),
        data = Table.FromList(response, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        expand = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(data, "Column1", {"id", "other columns of interest"}),
        newNextID = if Table.RowCount(expand) > 0 then expand{Table.RowCount(expand) - 1}[id] else null
    in
        [data = expand, nextID = newNextID],  

    limit = 250,
    count = countIdentities,
    totalPages = Number.RoundUp(count / limit),  

    // Fetch the first page of data, structured this way because including it in the loop was causing problems earlier as well
    firstPage = fetchPage(null, limit, 1), 
    initialData = firstPage[data],      
    initialNextID = firstPage[nextID],   

    // Loop to fetch subsequent pages, with page counter
    allData = List.Generate(
        () => [data = initialData, nextID = initialNextID, currentPage = 1],  
        each [nextID] <> null and [currentPage] <= totalPages,  // Continue as long as there are pages left and currentPage <= totalPages
        each let
            pageData = fetchPage([nextID], limit, [currentPage]+1),  // Fetch next page
            newData = Table.Combine({[data], pageData[data]}),  // Combine current data with new page data
            newNextID = pageData[nextID]  // Get nextID for the next iteration
        in
            [data = newData, nextID = newNextID, currentPage = [currentPage]+1],  // Move to the next page
        each [data]  // Return the accumulated data
    ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(allData, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "other columns of interest"}) 
    
in
    #"Expanded Column1"

My table structure is like this, with Column1.column name
column example
but then i get this error when it tries to do the next call
error when trying to iterate to the next call
I suspect it has something to do with expanding the table and the structure of the response being different. I've been stuck for quite a while, any help would be appreciated!
